# why does it urlpatterns give me page error?

Tags: django

I have the following in my urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # path('login/', views.login_user),
    # path('login/submit', views.submit_login),
    # path('logout/', views.logout_user),
    # path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='index/all')),
    path('', views.index),    
    path('index/all/', views.listar_all),    
    path('index/salgados/', views.listar_salgados),    
    path('index/esfirras/', views.listar_esfirras),  
    path('index/pizzas/', views.listar_pizzas),      
    path('index', views.submit),
    path('submit/', views.submit),
    path('index/all/submit/', views.submit),
]
```

I have the following in my view:

```
def index(request):
    print(request.POST)
    # if request.POST:        
    #Selecionar da tabela apenas os salgados ativos
    salgados = Salgado.objects.filter(active=True) 
    return render(request, 'index.html', {"salgados":salgados})

def listar_all(request):
    print(request.POST)
    # if request.POST:        
    #Selecionar da tabela apenas os salgados ativos
    salgados = Salgado.objects.filter(active=True) 
    # return render(request, 'index/', {"salgados":salgados})
    return render(request, 'index.html', {"salgados":salgados})

def listar_salgados(request):
    print(request.POST)
    # if request.POST:        
    #Selecionar da tabela apenas os salgados ativos
    salgados = Salgado.objects.filter(categoria='Salgados',active=True) 
    return render(request, 'index.html', {"salgados":salgados})


def listar_esfirras(request):
    print(request.POST)
    # if request.POST:        
    #Selecionar da tabela apenas os salgados ativos
    salgados = Salgado.objects.filter(categoria='Esfirras',active=True) 
    return render(request, 'index.html', {"salgados":salgados})

def listar_pizzas(request):
    print(request.POST)
    # if request.POST:        
    #Selecionar da tabela apenas os salgados ativos
    salgados = Salgado.objects.filter(categoria='Pizzas',active=True) 
    return render(request, 'index.html', {"salgados":salgados})

@csrf_protect 
def submit(request):
    print(request.POST)
    if request.POST:
    # return render(request, 'submit.html', {"salgados":salgados})  
    # return render(request, '/submit/', {"salgados":salgados})  
    return redirect('/')
```

The default view loads fine. The listar_pizzas in view works fine but when I click submit button it is giving me error like.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/salgados/submit

Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried 
these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
index/all/
index/salgados/
index/esfirras/
index/pizzas/
index
submit/
index/all/submit/
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
^templates/images/(?P<path>.*)$

The current path, index/salgados/submit, didn’t match any of these.
```

My navigations must be this:
Index.html --> view.listar_pizzas(just to filter) -> click submit button on index.html to send 2nd page saying thank you, but gives me this error instead when I click submit button.

I've tryied many combinations but can't figure it out.

Comment: `index/salgados/submit` != `index/salgados/`, likely you write that in your form tag somewhere...

Comment: The error occurs because you did not specify the route `/index/salgados/submit` in the urlpatterns.

Comment: Hi @Kishore I tryied this but now this error : RuntimeError at /index/esfirras/submit
You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/index/esfirras/submit/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.

Comment: Now it works thanks guys.
I put 
    return render(request, 'submit.html', {"salgados":salgados}) in views.submit and in urls I added these lines:     
    path('index/all/submit', views.submit),
    path('index/salgados/submit', views.submit),
    path('index/esfirras/submit', views.submit),    
    path('index/pizzas/submit', views.submit),